# AWS Instance Creatioin - create a instance in US West from a AMI created in US East

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a EC2 instance in US East . I want to launch exactly the same instance in US West .

The problem I am facing is that the AMI that I am creating with US East instance is not available when I change the region to US West in Aws.

Is there any workaround to use the AMI created in US East to launch a instance in US West.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to copy the AMI to another region. See this - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html

It says - *You can copy an AMI from one region to another, enabling you to launch consistent instances based from the same AMI into different regions.*

Answer (score 0):

The only for your case is to copy the AMI from US East to US West, that will enable you to launch same the instance in US West.

You can copy both Amazon EBS-backed AMIs and instance-store-backed AMIs to as many regions as you want but each copy of an AMI results in a new AMI with its own unique AMI ID.

Note: Prior to copying an AMI, you must ensure that the contents of the source AMI are updated to support running in a different region. For example, you should update any database connection strings or similar application configuration data to point to the appropriate resources. Otherwise, instances launched from the new AMI in the destination region may still use the resources from the source region, which can impact performance and cost.

[image]